# How to solve "No implementation found for method ensureInitialized on channel window_manager"?

Tags: flutter

When I run flutter project on chrome, this error occurs, after running the page is blank,  how to solve this problem?

```
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method ensureInitialized on channel window_manager)
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 288:49  throw_
packages/flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart 308:7                     _invokeMethod
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50            <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54                                          runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                    handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 784:44                                    handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 813:13                                    _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 584:5                                     [_completeWithValue]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 657:7                                     callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 177:15           <fn>
```

I have added this dependency in pubspec.yaml file.

Comment: Please add the `pubspec.yaml` file and `flutter doctor` .

Comment: ```flutter clean``` then ```flutter pub get``` in the project terminal

Answer (score 0):

You're using a Flutter package named [window_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/window_manager) in your Flutter web project. So, if you see the platform detail of [window_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/window_manager), it does not support the Flutter `Web` platform (perhaps it start support in future, no one knows). Its supported platforms are `Linux`, `MacOS` & `Windows` as of now.